# Add property to defined type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
const contacts = await this.prisma.contact.findMany({
  select: {
    id: true,
    name: true,
    mainSellerId: true,
    phone01: true

  }
})
```

And Prisma generates a custom type based on the parameters, like this:

```
const contacts: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    mainSellerId: number;
    phone01: string;
}[]
```

I want to add the property `lastMessage: string` to the contacts array like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  contacts[i].lastMessage = await findLastMessage(contacts[i])
}
```

Typescript will complain because there's no `lastMessage` property in `contacts`.

One solution is to create a new type and assign the contacts to another variable like this:

```
const losContacts: (typeof contacts[0] & { lastMessage?: string })[] = contacts

for (let i = 0; i < losContacts.length; i++) {
    losContacts[i].lastMessage = await findLastMessage(losContacts[i])
}
```

Another is to do this:

```
const findMany = () =>
    this.prisma.contact.findMany({
        select: {
            id: true,
            name: true,
            mainSellerId: true,
            phone01: true,
        },
    })

const contacts: (Awaited<ReturnType<typeof findMany>>[0] & { lastMessage?: string })[] = await findMany()

for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    contacts[i].lastMessage = await findLastMessage(contacts[i])
}
```

But these options feel like to much effort...

Can I just, somehow, say somethig like:

```
const contacts = /* await this.prisma.contact.findMany ... */

contacts: AddPropertyOrSomething<{ lastMessage?: string }>
```

And for that line onward `contacts` will have another prop. Or something that doesn't require me to specify the object entirely, like this:

```
const contacts: { id: number; name: string; mainSellerId: number; phone01: string; lastMessage?: string }[] = await this.prisma.contact.findMany({
    select: {
        id: true,
        name: true,
        mainSellerId: true,
        phone01: true,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of spreading and `map`:

```
const contacts = await Promise.all((await this.prisma.contact.findMany({
  select: {
    id: true,
    name: true,
    mainSellerId: true,
    phone01: true
  }
})).map(async (contact, index) => ({
    ...concact,
    lastMessage: await findLastMessage(contacts[i])
})));
```

This is because `{ ...A, b: x }` results in the type `A & { b: x }`.